# $cordovaSQLite.execute run late

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I'm making ionic app with cordova sqlite plugin.

but $cordovaSQLite.execute() function run late.

for example,

```
var set_info() { 
  console.log('before set_info'); 
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query).then(function(res) { 
     //... 
    console.log('execute success'); 
  }, function(err) { 
     console.log(err); 
  }); 
  console.log('after set_info'); 
; 
set_info();
```

console showed like this:

```
before set_info
after set_info 
execute success
```

but I want the result like this:

```
before set_info
execute success
after set_info
```

Anyone know about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success and error functions after 'execute' are asynchronous: They will be executer latter, and your code after (your log 'after set_info') will be executed before it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise

Comment: and then what should I write code like? I want to get results after excute.

Comment: The code you want to execute AFTER you need to put it inside the success and/or error functions.

Comment: @y.hr I've add a link in the answer

Comment: @y.hr if that answer your question, you can check the answer to validate it :)